# Send a POST message with UTF-8 special char with Wininet

Tags: c++, string, post, utf-8, wininet

I want to send a message on a PHP page using Wininet. My code is actually incompatible with UTF-8 special char like €, é, à. How to convert it ? I search a long time and I don't find the solution. I tried to use wstring but it the same problem. This is the source code :

```
void sendHello()
{
    LPCSTR header = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    std::string dataStr = "message=ééàà€€";
    LPVOID myMessage = (LPVOID)dataStr.c_str();
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA(hInternet, "127.0.0.1", 80, " ", " ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnection, "POST", "/SendMessage.php", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
    HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, header, strlen(header), myMessage, dataStr.size());
}
```

**I post a new question because a similar question has been posted by someone but the problem is not solved and solution pruposed doesn't works. (It's a StackOverflow recommandation to open a new question).
Thanks to @Barmak, @Shemirani, @Unheilig, @Daniel Widdis to keep it opened.**

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for [`HttpSendRequestA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-httpsendrequesta), `A` stands for ANSI. There is a Unicode version of the API where functions end in `W`, such as `HttpSendRequestW` which supports UTF-16 strings.

Comment: @Romen that applies to the `lpszHeaders` parameter, but not the `lpOptional` parameter, which takes arbitrary data and is sent as-is since it may be binary. `HttpSendRequestA` will happily send UTF-8 data in the POST body. I *suspect* the real problem will likely be the `std::string` not actually being UTF-8 encoded at runtime like the OP expects. Make sure the compiler is set to save the source code file and string literal data in UTF-8 to begin with. Also, the string data shown is not url-encoded properly. `HttpSendRequestA` will not do the url-encoding for you, you have to do it yourself

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Good point, they can use the `std::string myString = u8"abcdé";` [syntax for string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to force UTF-8 encoding right? As long as the code itself is saved in UTF-8 encoding...

Comment: I already tried `HttpSendRequestW` and the problem is the same. Also, char are not correctly encoded even if I use `std::string myString = u8"abcdé";` to declare the string.

Comment: @ErwanZAMBA "*char are not correctly encoded*" - then you have a bigger problem with your project that you need to track down

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, this is the final solution :

```
void sendHello()
{
    LPCSTR header = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    std::string dataStr = u8"message=ééàà€€";
    LPVOID myMessage = (LPVOID)dataStr.c_str();
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA(hInternet, "127.0.0.1", 80, " ", " ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnection, "POST", "/SendMessage.php", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
    HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, header, strlen(header), myMessage, dataStr.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not url-encoding the string data correctly. Non-ASCII and reserved characters need to be charset encoded to bytes and then the resulting bytes encoded in `%HH` format.

The UTF-8 encoded form of `ééàà€€` is bytes

> C3 A9 C3 A9 C3 A0 C3 A0 E2 82 AC E2 82 AC

So change this

```cpp
std::string dataStr = "message=ééàà€€";
```

To this

```cpp
std::string dataStr = "message=%C3%A9%C3%A9%C3%A0%C3%A0%E2%82%AC%E2%82%AC";`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but same problem.

Comment: @ErwanZAMBA then the problem is not in the code you have shown